# Recover HDFS Data Files of Internal Hive Table after dropping table

Tags: hive, azure-storage, data-recovery

I accidentally dropped an **Hive Internal Table**, inturn all the files associated with the internal table ( xyz_table) got automatically deleted from HDFS location ( /hive/warehouse/abc_mes.db/xyz_table/ )

We are using Azure HDInsight Cluster with Azure File Storage ( AFS ) as storage layer.

Can someone advise on how to recover the files on HDFS ..I checked in trash, i could see very old files like 4 months old files there, but could not find any recent files under /home//.trash ...

Appreciate if someone can guide

Cheers

Comment: The whole point of using a "managed" table _(what you call "internal")_ is that data files are deleted on a DROP command. That's the only difference with an "external" table. And Hive always skips the HDFS Trash. So you are screwed.

Comment: With real HDFS you could have taken a _snapshot_ of the Hive Warehouse dir every WE, but now it's too late, and you don't use HDFS anyway.

Comment: Thanks @SamsonScharfrichter, as far as i know Azure HDInsight Cluster along with Azure File Storage is more or less HDFS and supports all HDFS commands . BTW can you throw more light on snapshot process, or point me to a helpful link

Answer (score 1):

It's being long time after this question asked but I faced same issue and I want to share my experience.

First of all, I use Cloudera for HDFS-Hive-Hue. I dropped a table which associated  with HDFS location, and yes, I couldn't find files in /home/.Trash but in /user/admin/.Trash/Current/

It may help someone in the future.

Answer (score 0):

For CDH, CDP platform, The dropped table if HDFS Trash is configured, will be stored in Trash directory of the user which dropped the file.

For example, for user `abc`, the HDFS Trash directory will be `/user/abc/.Trash`.

Under this directory,  there will be directory structure like Hive warehouse directory structure which you dropped.
For example, for table dropped from `sample_db.test_table` by user `abc`, the HDFS files will be under `/user/abc/.Trash/Current/user/hive/warehouse/sample_db.db/test_table` provided that Hive warehouse directory is `/user/hive/warehouse`.

For Azure File Storage, it depends if the Trash is configured somehow as it's based on object storage.